# How to get next video to play?

Tags: wordpress

I have several videos that I want to put into a post/page as a lesson.  When one video finishes, the next video will play (assuming auto play is enabled by the user).  On the page, the video will appear.  Next to the video will be a scrollable list of topics.  Clicking a topic starts the respective video.  If auto play is enabled, the next video will play automatically.

Udacity has nice an example that is HTML/javascript based: http://d.pr/i/u49j.

Any ideas if there is a plugin like this or how it can be created?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this could be accomplished with a custom flash app, which would require you to have flash pro, and it uses flash, so that's not really a solution.

The only other way i can think of is to use YouTube playlists...

How do you plan on getting the videos in? Embedding or uploading? I think Microsoft used to have a page full of videos on how to use visual studio for k-12 students (ikr) anyway their silverlight videos played automatically I think

Comment: Thanks.  I will probably host them on Vimeo and embed into my site. I updated the post with a link of how it is done using HTML/Javascript.  Do you know if that is something that can be downloaded somewhere?  Looks simple but I know it isn't.